# Error: "cannot read property "div" of undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I keep getting this error

"Cannot read property 'div' of undefined"

This is my Code

```
function checkCard(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        if(animalNums[i].animal.textContent === findArray[i].div.textContent){
            animalNums[i].animal.style.display = "block"
            animalNums[i].animal.classList.add("animate");
            setTimeout(function(){animalNums[i].animal.classList.remove("animate");},1001)
            score += 1
            document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}` 
        }
    }
}
```

Its saying findArray[i].div is undefined
here is the array it is referencing :

```
let findArray = [ 
    {
       div: document.getElementById("findOne")
    },
    {
       div: document.getElementById("findTwo")
    },
    {
       div: document.getElementById("findThree")
    }
]
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I believe I have done a very similar function that worked before. Is this something to do with Scope?

Comment: Can you console log the array inside your function?

Comment: One question... why? Couldn't you accomplish the same thing by using the same class name and doing a selector on the class whilst looping through the class? I guess not, because only 0 to 2 are being 'got' on the `findArray[i].div.textContent` if statement, while the actual loop is for 0 to 12.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason this is happening is because you are iterating over the array with a value of `'i'` that is larger than the array length itself. You are using the value `i < 13` and incrementing 'i'. It is possible your array has less than 12 elements and when you are trying to get the value at the 12th index, you get 'undefined' because there isn't an index at that `'i'` value. Also one thing to keep in mind here is that Arrays are 0 based.

As you haven't shared the entire array therefore I cannot say for sure, but you can see the below example snippet to get an understanding of what I mean to say:

```js
let findArray = [
  {
    div: document.getElementById("findOne"),
  },
  {
    div: document.getElementById("findTwo"),
  },
  {
    div: document.getElementById("findThree"),
  },
];

(function checkCard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i, findArray[i].div);
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="findOne"></div>
<div id="findTwo"></div>
<div id="findThree"></div>
```

Therefore, the better thing to do here rather than passing a hardcoded value of `i < 13` is to pass value of `i` to be `<` `findArray.length` property like below:

```js
    let findArray = [
      {
        div: document.getElementById("findOne"),
      },
      {
        div: document.getElementById("findTwo"),
      },
      {
        div: document.getElementById("findThree"),
      },
    ];

    (function checkCard() {
      for (let i = 0; i < findArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(i, findArray[i].div);
      }
    })();
```

```html
<div id="findOne"></div>
    <div id="findTwo"></div>
    <div id="findThree"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sabbir.alam
Yes I can console.log the array inside the function.

@ShaneerM13
Yeah I am not sure this is the best way to write it. I more wanted to show the error I am getting because its happening with lots of different functions.

Comment: What is the length of your array? How many elements does it have?